# What does 'max' here do?

Tags: optimization, notation, convex-optimization

$\max_{i=1,...,k} $  $ |a^T_i x - b_i|$
I guess it affects expressions with $i$?
there's also this notation
$\max\limits_j$ is it same as $\max_j$?

Comment: It simply means the maximum of the set: $\{ |a_1^Tx-b_1|, ..., |a_k^Tx-b_k|\}$.

Comment: Yes, $\max_j$ is the same as $\displaystyle\max_j$. The former is better suited for in-line equations.